# Getting multiple images from frontmatter Markdown with GraphQL into Gatsby

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I'm trying to get a list of images into Gatsby with GraphQL from my markdown files. If I use one image, it works.

markdown list:

```
images:
  - ./images/01.jpg
  - ./images/02.jpg
  - ./images/03.jpg
```

query:

```
{
  allMarkdownRemark {
    edges {
      node {
        frontmatter {
          images {
            id
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

result:

```
"errors": [
{
  "message": "The \"path\" argument must be of type string. Received type object",
  "locations": [
    {
      "line": 6,
      "column": 11
    }
  ],
  "path": [
    "allMarkdownRemark",
    "edges",
    4,
    "node",
    "frontmatter",
    "images"
  ]
}
],
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does your `gatsby-config.js` look like?

Comment: I moved the images from the front-matter into the content area. Now it is working for me.